# How to set specific height of page

Tags: css, wordpress, web, height, html

I have problem with my webpage which I setup on Wordpress. I'd like to set fixed height there, so the footer is always visible and there is no scroll-bar on the  left. I've tried several methods already which I found on the web but nothing works. Do you have any suggestions?

[Link to webpage](http://biuro-accent.stronazen.pl/)

Comment: This works, I've used it multiple times: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this on your .footer-bottom class

```
.footer-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```